# Angular Number only input restrict 0

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm using Angular and I have a number only input,

Questions is I need to restrict 0.
Any suggestions please..

Comment: You can use Regex `[^0]`

Answer (score 1):

With the use of $parsers provided by **[NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)**, we can scan and remove zero from the number field.

I have created a directive which will restrict zero in the number field. Add it in your application.

Then you can use it on number input element to prevent the zero. It will still allow negative numbers.

Note : You need to use it as an attribute on input field. like `restrict-zero`

Example : `<input type="number" restrict-zero ng-model="number">`

**[See Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/epapnsAd3MRYXDeWWXCE?p=preview)**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.number = '';
  })
  .directive('restrictZero', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
          if (inputValue == null)
            return ''
          cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(/^0/g, '');
          if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return cleanInputValue;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Number : <input type="number" restrict-zero ng-model="number" name="number">
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `min='1'` attribute:

```html
<input type='number' min='1'>
```

But i guess you just need to restrict `0` only, so all other numbers positives and negatives would be insertable, so you can make a function and you can use `$event` of angular and get the `keyCode/stringvalue` and that can be restricted like:

```js
var app = angular.module('testapp', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.noZero = function(e) {
      var kc = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == '0' && e.target.value.indexOf('0') == 0) {
        return e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, -1);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='testapp' ng-controller='appCtrl'>
  <input type='number' ng-keyup='noZero($event)'>
</div>
```

Comment: Negative numbers are not excluded in OP's question

Comment: @axelduch agreed! then OP has to make a function on the scope and that keyCode can be restricted.

Comment: If I type **10** it is getting converted to **1**.

Comment: Now if I type 0 it is appears and suddenly disappears. Looks like its flickering.

Comment: does it matter? you just can't have 0 at first index.

Comment: @Jai It might. Nice answer though. Thumbs up.

Comment: No problem! @VVK seems OP has not interested in the answers, yet +1.